# Does ADFS 2.0 supports the SAML 1.1 protocol and Web SSO profiles?

Tags: saml, adfs2.0

Does ADFS 2.0 supports the SAML 1.1 protocol and Web SSO profiles as mentionend in this [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAML_1.1) or are only SAML 1.1 tokens supported?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to my research ADFS 2.0 supports WS-Federation and the SAML 2.0 protocol (SAML-P). SAML 1.1 is only supported as a token format. This makes sense as WS-Federation supports various token formats including SAML 2.0 and SAML 1.1. So there is SAML 1.1 support because of the token issue...